SQLite query to chunk group_concat into groups that maximize a length constraint?
I have data in a SQLite table that I'd like to process in "chunks" that include concatenated fields of multiple rows up to an overall limit of 10,000 chars per chunk. I can run queries multiple times and write temp tables, if it helps. But, I don't want to run data from the same rows multiple times.  My primary constraint is the overall length of the individual chunks.  I want to maximize each output chunk by concatenating multiple rows until I can't fit any more up to a length limit of 10,000 chars.
The data looks a bit like this:
ID    Customer    Purchase
1     john        2x bolts, 2x screws, 5x lumber
2     jim         3x lumber, 1x screws, 14x nails
3     john        15x screws, 2x sodas, 2x, hotdogs
4     jim         1x foobars
etc...

Assuming my length limit was 50 chars per group_concat(ed) "Purchase", we disregard the IDs, and group based on "Customer", I'd want the output to create two chunks for john but one for jim. (because both of jim's purchase strings can be concatenated and remain within the 50 char limit)
If my chunk limit was 35, I'd have 4 chunks.  If it were 100, I'd have 2.
The purpose is to get as much data into a single LLM prompt as it can accept at once without overloading it.  I am ultimately combining multiple JSONs (the "Purchase" field) associated with a single Customer and having the LLM distill the JSONs down into a single one that includes only the relevant information from each.  I suspect, I'll have to make multiple passes since a Customer could have 100k characters worth of JSONs that need processing and I'll have to reprocess even the distilled LLM outputs.  Luckily, I don't have any individual rows that are already longer than 10k chars.
Bonus points if the padding of a chunk can be smart enough to fill in a chunk with the data from additional rows for processing based on the length available before hitting the limit and selecting source rows whose length are >= ( limit - current chunk length)
I'm working with SQLite on Ubuntu 24 and Python 3.12 if it matters.
Doing some of the above processing within Python is also an option.
I've tried asking the AI's out there including Github Copilot and they either didn't fully understand the concept, or they didn't produce usable queries that SQLite could handle.  Or it would only process the first 10k chars for a given Customer and not create any additional chunks for that customer.

This isn't perfect, but it should be good enough. The idea is to create groups wherever all the previous rows for a customer cross a multiple of your chunk size, then group_concat those groups.
Since you're using chunks of 10000 it shouldn't be a big deal, but if you have a 9000 long purchase, then 2000, then 9000, then 2000, there will be 4 groups despite obviously being able to combine the 2 2000s. You may want to fiddle with ordering if you have long values like that.
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    Customer,
    Purchase,
    (SUM(LENGTH(Purchase)+2) OVER ( -- +2 for the length of the group_concat separator
      PARTITION BY Customer ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    )-1-2)/10000 as LengthGroup -- -2 to only count separators between values, -1 to get the grouping right
  FROM purchases
)
SELECT
  Customer,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Purchase, ', ') AS Purchases
FROM cte
GROUP BY Customer, LengthGroup;

